# Why are canvas operations not relative to containing object?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In a Windows Firemonkey application, when I issue the following for a rectangle, in the middle of a form:

```
rect.Canvas.BeginScene;
rect.Canvas.Clear(TAlphaColorRec.White);
rect.Canvas.EndScene
```

the entire form is painted white.

Was not the case in XE2. Is the case in Delphi 10.

What's the new paradigm I have overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas of the *primitive* (e.g `TPaintBox` and all `TShape` descendants) controls, is the canvas of the form. The controls draw directly on this canvas. Therefore a call to `Control.Canvas.Clear()` clears the whole form. Instead of calling `Clear` you should use the `Fill` property of the `TRectangle`, like so:

```
Rectangle1.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
```

I can't comment on how it was in Delphi XE2, but there has been many changes to the FMX library, since then. Maybe this is one of them.

Also refer to [FireMonkey Component Rendering](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/FireMonkey_Component_Rendering)

Comment: Thanks. I tested with rect.Canvas.ClearRect(rect.AbsoluteRect,TAlphaColorRec.White). I guess I'll be using the SetMatrix method a whole lot from now on.